# How to start Microsoft SQL server Management and chose a server

Tags: ssms

I have downloaded SSMS and I am trying to figure out how to chose a "server" in order to log in and see how it works. However, I can't understand from where I "create" or "pick" the server from which I am supposed to create the connection for the DB.

I have no idea how to start it or pick a server. 
[image]

Is what I get when turn on the application. 
 What should I do in order to start the application? Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server? You ask how do you start SSMS, but you clearly have started it in the image.

Comment: I asked how to pick a server and start a connection to a server.

Comment: That's not what i asked. Have you installed [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-2019)?

Comment: Is there a free version that I can install ?( not an evaluation version)

Comment: You'll want Developer or Express; depending on your use case.